# Liquibase with Maven using Teradata

Tags: liquibase-sql

I am getting the following error, while running the command: mvn liquibase:update
**liquibase.exception.databaseexception:connection could not be created to jdbc:teradata://org.sys.db.com/database=sample_DEV with driver com.teradata.jdbc.TestDriver [Teradata Database] [Terajdbc 16.20.00.00] [Error] [SQLState HY000] Logons are only enabled for user DBC.**

We are using maven version:3.6.3, Liquibase version:4.3.0 and teradata ver:16.20.00.00 with dbchangelog.sql
The same code is working fine for nornal project, i mean without maven.

Answer (score 0):

"com.teradata.jdbc.TestDriver" is not the class name for the Teradata JDBC Driver. The actual class name is "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver".

Version 16.20.00.00 of the Teradata JDBC Driver was not released to the public. That was a pre-release build.

You can download the current supported version of the Teradata JDBC Driver from here:

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

Here is a link to the Teradata documentation for database error 3055 "Logons are only enabled for user DBC."

https://docs.teradata.com/r/GVKfXcemJFkTJh_89R34UQ/Si5mPxDLg2vugG5MnDbBoQ